# If image is null from JSON, use another image - AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, wordpress, angularjs-ng-repeat, wp-api

Below I have an ng-repeat where the inner div gets a background image set after reading a JSON file.

My question is - If `post.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url` does not exist or is null, what would be the best approach to replace this with another image? Say a default backup image? A solution or tips to what to look for is what I am after as I am relatively new to AngularJS.

Code is below:

```
<article ng-repeat="post in posts">
   <div style="background-image: url({{ post.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url }})"></div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ng-style:

```
<article ng-repeat="post in posts">
   <div ng-style="post.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url === null ? {'background-image': 'url(/yourimage.jpg)' } : {'background-image': 'url('+post.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url+')' }"></div>
</article>
```